How to solve the issue Unsupported Media Type","status":415 in Jmeter?
Get Request:
I have also added the HTTP Header Manager - Content-Type application/json
Error:
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-d5313b4332758c49afde29f4377ccc34-632cc87037f26141-00"}


Share the endpoint/API which causes this issue?

As per 415 Unsupported Media Type documentation:

The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response status code indicates that the server refused to accept the request because the message content format is not supported.
The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of processing the request message content. Some servers may be strict about the expected Content-Type of requests. For example, sending UTF8 instead of UTF-8 to specify the UTF-8 charset may cause the server to consider the media type invalid.

So make sure to:

Add HTTP Header Manager as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which gives you the error
Send the necessary Content-Type and/or Content-Encoding headers
Make sure that headers values are correct and don't contain typos and unprintable characters like whitespaces or line breaks

